# combination product through sql

Tags: sql

I store option values and categories in a table.

I want to get one column with all possible combinations of option values.

For example:

- Option category ID are (1,2,5)
- Option values are {(31,39,55),(61,62),(98,99)}

I want a listing like this, in one column:

```
31
61
98

31
61
99

31
62
98

31
62
99

39
61
98

39
61
99

39
62
98


39
62
99

55
61
98

55
61
99

55
62
98

55
62
99
```

Please see below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just leave it here for you to work with it

Schema, data sample and query you show.

```
select * into #a from(
select 1 prod,1 id union all
select 1,2 union all
select 1,5 )a

select * into #b from(
select 1 id,31 cat union all
select 1,39 union all
select 1,55 union all
select 2,61 union all
select 2,62 union all
select 5,98 union all
select 5,99  ) b


select * from #a a inner join #b b on a.id=b.id
```

And this retrieves one row of tree items you look for, in order you need

```
select b1.cat 'a', b2.cat 'b', b3.cat 'c'  from #b b1, #b b2, #b b3, #a a1 
where a1.id=b1.id and b2.id>a1.id and b3.id>a1.id and b3.id>b2.id
    and b1.cat<b2.cat and b2.cat<b3.cat
order by b1.cat, b2.cat, b3.cat
```

I'll come back latter